Acceleration issue while pressing accelerator
I have recently replace engine Vitz Toyota and now car is not moving fast when press accelerator but fine on reverse side. dash board show tap sign on screen what could be the problem please guide?/

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

When you say it doesn't accelerate correctly, wondering exactly what you mean. Does the engine rev loud and the vehicle just doesn't go anywhere (quickly)? Or does the engine sound like it is bogging while not going anywhere fast? How is it different from before the engine install?
